# Spring MVC: ProducesRequestCondition not work properly?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Consider the following code:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/images/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public Image get(@PathVariable String domain, @PathVariable String id) {
    // Return Image object here
}

@GetMapping(path = "/images/{id}", produces = "!application/json")
public byte[] getBytes(@PathVariable String domain, @PathVariable String id) {
    // Return Byte array here
}
```

If I add the header "Accept: * / *" to the request, both mappings are matched.
But if I add the header "Accept: * / *;q=0.8" to the request, only the first mapping is matched.

Comment: What spring version are you using ?

Comment: The version is 4.3.2.RELEASE